# REDIS as session manager for servlet/jsp application

Tags: azure, servlets, redis, httpsession, spring-session

We have a legacy servlet/jsp application which uses HTTP sessions to store and retrieve data. We are planning to migrate that app to cloud and we want to use REDIS as session manager instead of web container(ex:-Tomcat).

I have seen spring session implementation to leverage REDIS to back a web application’s HttpSession when using Spring Boot.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/guides/boot-redis.html

I am looking for approach to handle it in legacy servlets application. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try redis based tomcat session management. Something like explained here
[Redis based tomcat session management](https://dzone.com/articles/redis-based-tomcat-session-management)